# Covering vertices of a graph by cycles (not necessarily disjoint)

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

As title says, I want to find $k$ cycles of a graph $G$ such that each vertex appears *at least* once in a cycle.  Let's count a single vertex as a cycle.

To be more specific, I'd like to have some upper bounds on $k$ with respect to any kind of graph parameter.  How many cycles are needed?  Is anything published on the matter?  This is a mainly reference request.

A search on the topic gives me many results on edge-disjoint or vertex-disjoint cycle covers.  Upper bounds are linear on the number of edges or vertices, mainly due to the "disjoint" requirement.
If we drop this, what kind of bounds do we get?  I can't seem to find much.

Best I've seen so far is an upper bound of $\alpha/\kappa + 1$ (independence number over connectivity), an extension of the Erdos-Chvatal Theorem.